# how do I get artwork of mp3 using AudioToolbox framework?

Tags: ios5, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to get artwork of the mp3 file using these lines of code.

```
    CFDataRef AlbumPic= nil;
    UInt32 picDataSize = sizeof(picDataSize);
    err =AudioFileGetGlobalInfo(kAudioFilePropertyAlbumArtwork, 0, NULL, &picDataSize, &AlbumPic);
    if( err != noErr ) {
        NSLog( @"error" );
    }


    NSData* imagedata= (__bridge NSData*)AlbumPic;
    UIImage* image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imagedata];
```

If I'm using:

```
NSLog (@"image %@, image");
```

or

```
NSLog (@"image %@, [image description]");
```

there is NULL.

How can I get artwork of mp3 file using kAudioFilePropertyAlbumArtwork?

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is `AudioFileGetProperty`, not `AudioFileGetGlobalInfo`